# Variable count is not set in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want `$id` to increase by 1 every time the form is submitted. Then it should be appended to the array `$users.`

Why is this not working?

```
<?php
$users = array();
$id = 0;

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $id = $id + 1;
    $users[] = $id;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($users);
echo "</pre>";
?>
<form action="random.php">
    buy a ticket
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Form defaults to GET when a method isn't defined. Do `<form action="random.php" method="post">`

Comment: ok, that was silly thing to forget , however now the count does not change every time i submit the form again

Comment: And use session variables, becasue when you submit the form, you are reinitialize your array and your id.

Answer (score 3):

This is because once the PHP code stops executing the value of `$id` and `$users` is gone forever. HTTP and PHP is stateless. Once that page is processed it is gone and it is like it never existed. If you want to persist state you need to use a persistent data store like sessions or database.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        if (!isset($_SESSION['users'])) { $_SESSION['users'] = 0 }
        $_SESSION['users']++;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_SESSION['users']);
    echo "</pre>";


?>
<form action="random.php" method="post">
    buy a ticket
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

---

**N.B.:** Forms defaults to GET when a method isn't defined, therefore it needs the `method="post"` since you are working with POST variables.

Comment: Plus, the omitted POST method ;)

Comment: A very important detail!

Comment: You forgot to change the $id at $_SESSION['users'][] = $id. Must be the session id

Comment: @Chilion After reviewing their code and better ascertaining their intentions I modified the code to remove id as I don't think it i necessary. But the above code is to better illustrate the point of saving state and *hopefully* points the OP in the right direction.

Comment: could you please explain how the variable are being defined? is $_SESSION["id"] bassically the same as saying $id ?

Comment: I eliminated the $id variable as it was not needed, at least in not the sample code you provided. But you can declare and use session variables just like any other variable just as long as you have `session_start()` at the top of your page.